# Capacitor calculation problem

Tags: voltage, capacitor

There is a capacitor that is charged to 20V. When we connect 1.5 megOhm resistor to it, it takes 6.1 seconds for the capacitor's output voltage to drop to 2V. How do I calculate the capacitance of the capacitor?

Comment: Try to find an equation that relates the capacitor's value, voltage, the value of the load resistance and time. You know the resistance, voltage and drop over time so you can solve for capacitance.

Comment: I=C*dU/dt. Differentiate and insert your figures.

Comment: At 20v, what current will flow through the resistor? And at 19v? Now if you haven't been introduced to differential equations, this may be a tough one to crack by yourself. Look up exponential decay.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.  You have to show some effort yourself, and a willingness to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the information given, we can use the following equation for the voltage at any time in a discharging capacitor:

$$V = V_0e^{-{t \over RC}}$$

Then, rearranging:

$${V \over V_0} = e^{-{t \over RC}}$$

$$\ln\left({V \over V_0}\right) = \ln\left(e^{-{t \over RC}}\right)$$

$$\ln\left({V \over V_0}\right) = {-{t \over RC}}$$

$$C = -{t \over R*\ln\left({V \over V_0}\right)} $$

And, entering your values:

$$C = - {6.1 \over 1.5*10^6 * \ln({2 \over 20})} \approx 1.77 \mu F $$

Comment: I gave him the full solution because it seems pointless not to do so. Simply giving him the equation could work, but if he has knowledge of log rules then rearranging should be a breeze - otherwise, it is helpful to show him how you can manipulate the equation. Perhaps I could have left out throwing the values in, but it's a simple process that wouldn't be a challenge to most people. Additionally, would you mind pointing out the issue with units? I couldn't spot it out myself, but I'm keen to learn if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Additionally worth noting is that the unedited question suggested the user had put in effort to solve the problem before posting.

Comment: hey im sorry. I edited this question for clarity and removed the parts which implied the user has put an effort. Am I supposed to leave them when I edit next time?

Comment: It's not a problem - many would argue that it's actually better to have the question without any irrelevant information. I only mentioned it as a response to the other user's comment.

Comment: @Qwert: In this case you just removed stupid fluff.  Your edit was just fine.  The original didn't show any real work.  The OP claiming he's been thinking about it for a while without showing any actual work is content-free.  You were right to remove it.

Comment: Your last equation equates a dimensionless quantity to a value in uF.  Also, I wasn't suggesting you derive all the equations, then stop short of filling in the numbers. That would be pointless, as you say.  For homework problems, you should only describe the general procedure at a high level and let the student figure out the details.

Comment: In my last equation, am I not equating seconds per ohm to micro farads? As far as my understanding goes, the two are equivalent, and neither side is dimensionless - although the result of the natural log is.